# Mysql Group BY with if statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, group-by

I'm not sure if this is something you can do in a single select statement without nesting selects.

I am grouping my results and I want to know IF a field inside the entire grouping contains a condition, display yes. With this it will just take the first row from the group and check the condition instead of all the rows in the group

```
if(field = 'condition','yes','no') as field_found
```

Comment: Can you post the query you are working with?

Comment: Figured it out: 
if(GROUP_CONCAT(field) LIKE '%condition%','yes','no')

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.  Please post your solution as an answer and mark as accepted.  This will remove your question from the unanswered list.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't have a high enough rep, lol

Answer (score 1):

example table: id, score

```
SELECT t1.id, (
  SELECT IF("10" IN (
    SELECT score FROM table t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id
  ),'yes','no')) 
FROM table t1
GROUP BY t1.id
```

does that work?

Comment: That should work but I'm trying not to nest selects as the query to find the condition has 4 inner joins already... so each nested select would have 4 inner joins and I have 6 conditions I'm checking for which would be 6 conditions with 4 inner joins each and BLAH!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already doing a group by, you should be able to add a MAX() as a column having the condition you are expecting and just add that to the group... such as

```
select 
      MAX( if( field LIKE '%condition%','1', '2' )) as ExtraOrderBy,
      First_Name,
      Last_Name,
      ... rest of query ...
   group by
      customers.Customer_ID
   order by
      1
```

In this case, the order by is the ordinal column in the SQL list instead of explicit retyping the MAX( IF() ) condition...  So, if the condition is true, mark it with "1", otherwise "2" will float all those that qualify to the top of the list... Then, you could sub-order by other things like last name, first name, or other fields you have queried.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(GROUP_CONCAT(field) LIKE '%condition%','yes','no')

SELECT first_name,last_name, CONCAT(physical_address," ",physical_address2," ",city, " ",zip) as address, MONTHNAME(install_date) as billing_month, IFNULL(status.quantity,0) as total_measures_instalclient2d,IFNULL(client1_measures,"") as client1_measures,IFNULL(client2_measures,"") as client2_measures,IFNULL(client1_quantity,0) as client1_quantity,IFNULL(client2_quantity,0) as client2_quantity,if(GROUP_CONCAT(measure_list.measure_type) LIKE '%Outreach/ Assessment%','yes','no') as outreach_invoiced,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(client='Client1',CONCAT(percent*100,"%-",measure_list.measure_type),NULL)) as client1_percent,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(client='Client2',CONCAT(percent*100,"%-",measure_list.measure_type),NULL)) as client2_percent,work_order.notes FROM customers
INNER JOIN measure on measure.customer_id = customers.customer_id
INNER JOIN measure_list on measure_list.measure_list_id = measure.measure_list_id
INNER JOIN work_order on work_order.work_order_id = measure.work_order_id
INNER JOIN billing on billing.workmanship = work_order.workmanship AND billing.measure_type = measure_list.measure_type
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT customers.customer_id,SUM(quantity) as quantity,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(client='Client1',measure_description,NULL)) as client1_measures,GROUP_CONCAT(IF(client='client2',measure_description,NULL)) as client2_measures,SUM(IF(client='client1',quantity,0)) as client1_quantity,SUM(IF(client='client2',quantity,0)) as client2_quantity FROM customers
INNER JOIN measure on measure.customer_id = customers.customer_id
INNER JOIN measure_list on measure_list.measure_list_id = measure.measure_list_id
INNER JOIN work_order on work_order.work_order_id = measure.work_order_id
INNER JOIN billing on billing.workmanship = work_order.workmanship AND billing.measure_type = measure_list.measure_type
WHERE measure_list.measure_type NOT IN ('measure1','measure2')
GROUP BY customers.customer_id
) as status on status.customer_id = customers.customer_id
WHERE measure_list.measure_type IN ('measure1','measure2')
GROUP BY customers.customer_id
```